# SQL: Sum of count statements containing where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, where-clause

I have 3 count statements, which I need to combine and take a sum of.

```
SELECT COUNT(status) 
FROM tableA 
WHERE env='test' 
AND deploy_date='2016-10-19' 
AND  platform='MA' 
AND server='B' 
AND status='5';

SELECT COUNT(status) 
FROM tableA 
WHERE env='test' 
AND deploy_date='2016-10-19'  
AND  platform='MA'  
AND server='B' 
AND status='3';

SELECT COUNT(status) 
FROM tableA 
WHERE env='test' 
AND deploy_date='2016-10-19' 
AND  platform='MA' 
AND server='B' 
AND status='1';
```

I tried

```
SELECT (select count(status) 
FROM tableA 
WHERE env='test' 
AND deploy_date='2016-10-19' 
AND  platform='MA' 
AND server='B' and status='5'; ) + 
(SELECT COUNT(status) 
FROM tableA WHERE env='test' 
AND deploy_date='2016-10-19' 
AND  platform='MA' 
AND server='B' AND status='3';) + 
(SELECT COUNT(status) 
FROM tableA
WHERE env='test' 
AND deploy_date='2016-10-19' 
AND  platform='MA' 
AND server='B' AND status='1';)
```

But getting syntax error. What am I missing? Is there a better way to accomplish this in MySQL. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: how about where status in (5,3,1) if numbers

Comment: @Drew sorry, can you elaborate? I am not used to SQL much.

Comment: `select count(status) from tableA where env='test' and deploy_date='2016-10-19' and  platform='MA' and server='B' and status in (5,3,1);` or `select count(status) from tableA where env='test' and deploy_date='2016-10-19' and  platform='MA' and server='B' and status in ('5','3','1');`  ... depending on the datatype of `status`

Comment: Regarding the syntax error: remove the semicolons within the Subqueries. Btw, why don't you add the actual error message?

Comment: @dnoeth  thanks,  once the semicolon is removed from sub queries it worked. But smaller queries in below answer is better.

Comment: Of course, that's why I wrote *Regarding the syntax error* :) There might be just one reason to use your original query: The individual Selects utilize an index while the single Select using `IN` doesn't (check the plan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to combine

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM   tableA
WHERE  env = 'test'
       AND deploy_date = '2016-10-19'
       AND platform = 'MA'
       AND server = 'B'
       AND status IN ( '5', '3', '1' );
```

Comment: I am getting this error
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[stat5],
       Sum(status = '3') [stat3],
       Sum(status = '1') [stat1]
FROM' at line 1`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one, it is very simple query.

```
SELECT status, count(status) from tableA 
WHERE env='test' AND deploy_date='2016-10-19' AND platform='MA' AND server='B' AND status in ('1','3','5')
Group by status
```

above will return individual count and sum if you want sum of all then just remove **group by** clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(status)
FROM   tableA 
WHERE  env = 'test'
   AND deploy_date = '2016-10-19'
   AND platform = 'MA'
   AND server = 'B'
   AND status IN ( '5', '3', '1' );
```

You can combine the statement into one, status differ, rest all the filtration are same.

For status wise count, add group by clause `Group By Status` at the end of the SQL script.

```
SELECT Status,count(status)
FROM   tableA
WHERE  env = 'test'
   AND deploy_date = '2016-10-19'
   AND platform = 'MA'
   AND server = 'B'
   AND status IN ( '5', '3', '1' )
Group By Status
```